# In R package `factoextra` , using `get_dist`can calculate distance between variables,how to change the result into data.frame format

Tags: r, factoextra

In R package `factoextra` , using `get_dist`can calculate distance between variables,how to change the result into data.frame format ? Thanks!
Below code return `cannot coerce class ‘"dist"’ to a data.frame`

```
library(factoextra)
data("USArrests")
res.dist <- get_dist(USArrests,stand = TRUE, method ="pearson")
res.dist %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: I don't have that package -- is it returning a triangle matrix like a distance matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `as.matrix` first.

Using pipes

```
res.dist %>% as.matrix() %>% as.data.frame()
```

Nested function calls

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(res.dist))
```